# Как правильно оформить цитаты?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли оформлено следующее предложение?

Тогда мы и слышим сверху классические фразы, такие как «нефть не может упасть ниже 70 долл. за баррель» (а она упала), «рост курса доллара по отношению к рублю создает прочную основу для выполнения социальных обязательств», «не суетитесь», «вкладывайте не в валюту, а в товары, недвижимость и пр.».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оформление верное, цитаты здесь составляют однородный ряд, отнесенный к обобщающему слову "классические фразы". Запятая ставится перед словом "такие".

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_722

В некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой», в частности если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед рядом однородных членов (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не требуется): Туристы посетили старинные города, такие как Суздаль, Владимир, Ростов Великий.

Comment: Спасибо большое.